# Accessing updated props from parent stateless function component from child stateless class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

child component

```
export class child extends Component {
  buttonclick() {
    const { pin } = this.props
    if (pin === null) {
      add().then(result => {
        updatePin(result.data)
      })
    } else {
      remove(pin.id).then(result => {
        updatePin(result)
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { pin } = this.props
    const label =
     pin === null
        ? 'yes'
        : 'no'

    const icon =pin === null ? 'yes' : 'no'

    return (
      <div>
          <Button
            icon={icon}
            label={label}
            onClick={() => this.buttonclick()}
          />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

parent component(classless component)

```
    const parent= props =>{
        const { pins = []} = props
        const { pin } = Data
    }
    const updatePin = result => {
    // here iam updating the pin
   }
      const renderchildComponent=()=>{
    return(
        <div>
         <ChildComponent
                pin={pin}
                updatePin={result => updatePin(result)}
              />
       </div>
    )
    }
```

here in the above code the pin is updating in the parent component but how to pass it to child component every time when the button click happens without refreshing the page. please help me out with this

Comment: Is the pin inside of your props or in your parent state? If neither the props nor the state of the parent change, they won't be a re render

Comment: Thanks for the answer......yes it is inside of props ... and in the parent component the props are updating..... can you make changes in the above code to work?

Comment: You're mutating directly the  pin object so for React it didn't change. You need to either use some state inside of your parent  component or use a function to modify the pin props given to the parent component. In React, you should pretty much consider that every value is immutable.